# How do I make effective use of the formula for calculating the product of the members of a finite arithmetic progression?

Tags: probability, arithmetic-progressions

Here's a question I was tasked to answer with limited knowledge/use of combinatorics:

In a class of 25 students, every student gets to pick a number 1 to 100. What is the probability that at least two students pick the same number?

My solution:

First I look at the complementary event, where every student picks a unique number. The first student has 100 unique numbers, the second 99, the third 98, and so on. Mathematically I express it like so:

$\frac{100}{100}\times\frac{99}{100}\times\frac{98}{100}\times\cdots\times\frac{76}{100}$

and as it would be tedious to compute on a calculator, I rewrote it somewhat:

$\frac{1}{100^{24}}\times\frac{99!}{75!}$

Which you then take the complementary probability of (which is the probability of at least two people having the same number)

$P = 1 - \frac{1}{100^{24}}\times\frac{99!}{75!}\approx0.962\rightarrow96.2\%$

Now, in my pursuit to provide a more elegant answer, I stumbled upon the [Arithmetic progression Wikipedia page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Arithmetic_progression#:%7E:text=An%20arithmetic%20progression%20or%20arithmetic,a%20common%20difference%20of%202.) and found that "The product of the members of a finite arithmetic progression with an initial element $a_1$, common differences d, and n elements in total" can be expressed as:

$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(a_1+kd\right)=d^{n}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a_1}{d}+n\right)}{\Gamma\left (\frac{a_1}{d}\right)}$

So I tried it with my numbers, but the answer is completely bananas. Therefore I assume I made a mistake somewhere, but as I have limited experience with the formula I do currently not see the error.

$\prod_{k=0}^{24}\left(1-\frac{1}{100}k\right)=\left ( \frac{1}{100} \right )^{25}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{100}}+25\right)}{\Gamma\left (\frac{1}{\frac{1}{100}}\right)}$

As $\Gamma$ denotes the "Gamma function", and the input is a positive integer for both instances of the Gamma function, we should be able to rewrite it like so:

$\Gamma \left ( n \right )=\left ( n-1 \right )!$

$\prod_{k=0}^{24}\left(1-\frac{1}{100}k\right)=\left ( \frac{1}{100} \right )^{25}\frac{\left ( 125-1 \right )!}{\left ( 100-1 \right )!}$

$\frac{1}{100^{25}}\times \frac{124!}{99!}\approx 16.1$

Which instantly can be dismissed as an incorrect probability! So my question is, how can I make use of this formula in regards to providing an answer for the question I was tasked with?

Comment: Since every term in the product is positive and  $≤1$ it is impossible to get a product of $16.1$

Comment: Note that the page you link to contains the warning: "The formula is not valid when $\frac {a_1}d$ is negative or zero."

Comment: @lulu Thanks! I understand the latter comment, but what do you mean by the first? Also, is there an alternative formula I could use for this problem?

Comment: Just pointing out that the computation was obviously incorrect.  As to the original problem, [The Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) has been extensively written about, and this is just a rephrasing of that.

Comment: @lulu Where did the computation become incorrect? I don't see it.

Comment: Since, as you say, $\Gamma \left ( n \right )=\left ( n-1 \right )!$, it does not make the calculation easier.  You should have had $n=25, a_1=76, d=1$ to get $\frac{1}{100^{25}}\times \frac{\Gamma(101)}{\Gamma(76)} = \frac{1}{100^{25}}\times \frac{100!}{75!}= \frac{1}{100^{24}}\times \frac{99!}{75!}$, i.e. your earlier calculation

Comment: As I pointed out, the formula you use is not applicable to this problem. That's the point of the warning the site you link to provides